# Django Template > checking condition on button click

Tags: django

On my template i have a button to collect fee that takes the user to next screen. However, i want a check on this button's click event if the fee is already paid-in-full and prompts the user via message on screen.
In related model i have method that checks if fee is paid in full. I had added the condition on template like this and it disabled the button

```
<td><a href="{% url 'add_fee' student.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm {% if student.get_remaining_fee == 0 %}disabled {% endif %}">Add Fee</a></td>
```

but this increases the number of queries as i have a many students records on current view.

In general if i want such validations before user can go to new/assigned view, what would be the best practice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked for best practices followed, I will point out a few:

1. Pagination, use offset and limit for fetching the list of Students - have a look at index function [here](https://github.com/addu390/django-pyblog/blob/master/blog/views.py) - thereby preventing too many database calls in one go.
2. Getting such information ideally shouldn't require extra DB calls, the table joins should suffice - thereby taking away the need for several database calls.

Note: I'm not suggesting changing the view/ user experience, as that would be out of the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will look for pagination piece in detail. However, i had this check as shown above and it slows the page down. Loading time is very slow as there are many students. I removed this check from inputs which made it super fast as only two queries are hitting the DB. I am thinking of changing the page design to have only one button and that is why i need to call a function either through javascript or django view so i can deal with this in one shot.